# Project Euler 17 using Python 2.7

Tags: python

I've been trying to solve Problem 17 of project euler. However my answer is 21088 but the correct answer is 21124. My answer should be 36 higher. I can't figure out what is wrong. Could anyone help?

Code:

```
dict = {0: '', 1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 5: 'five', 6: 'six', 7: 'seven', 8: 'eight', 9: 'nine',
              10: 'ten', 11: 'eleven', 12: 'twelve', 13: 'thirteen', 14: 'fourteen', 15: 'fifteen', 16: 'sixteen',
            17: 'seventeen', 18: 'eighteen', 19: 'nineteen', 20: 'twenty', 30: 'thirty', 40: 'forty', 50: 'fifty',
            60: 'sixty', 70: 'seventy', 80: 'eighty', 90: 'ninety', 100: 'hundred', 1000: 'onethousand'}

def pronounce(number):

    if number < 21:
        words = dict[number]

    string = str(number)
    if 21 <= number < 100:
        words = dict[int(string[0])*10] + dict[int(string[1])]

    if 100 <= number < 1000:
        words = dict[int(string[0])] + dict[100] + 'and' + dict[int(string[1])*10] + dict[int(string[2])]

    if number % 100 == 0:
        words = dict[int(string[0])] + dict[100]

    if number == 1000:
        words = dict[1000]

    return words

full = ''

for i in range(1,1001):
    full += pronounce(i)

print full

print len(full)
```

Comment: What’s the problem statement? Also, please format your code correctly by inserting four spaces in front of every line. The “Code Sample” button in the editor toolbar (Ctrl+K) will do this for you.

Comment: Tip: do not use Python built-in functions as variable names. In this case, do not use `dict`, but something like `my_dict`.

Comment: You don't mention what project Euler's problem #17 is; you don't mention what the goal of your program is. Since we don't want to search around for it (and not everything will know by heart what it is), you should [edit] your question to update it with the relevant information.

Comment: Anyway, it looks like you’ll be producing things like “one hundred and ten three”.

Comment: minitech is exactly right (and it is your only fundamental problem). Writing out tenone ... tennine is 4 characters less than eleven ... nineteen. 4 * 9 (100, 200, ..., 900) is the 35 missing characters. Rewrite the statement for number between 100 and 1000 and you will get the correct answer. I.e., when number mod 100 is less than 10 use different logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
nums = {0: '', 1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 5: 'five', 6: 'six', 7: 'seven', 8: 'eight', 9: 'nine',
              10: 'ten', 11: 'eleven', 12: 'twelve', 13: 'thirteen', 14: 'fourteen', 15: 'fifteen', 16: 'sixteen',
            17: 'seventeen', 18: 'eighteen', 19: 'nineteen', 20: 'twenty', 30: 'thirty', 40: 'forty', 50: 'fifty',
            60: 'sixty', 70: 'seventy', 80: 'eighty', 90: 'ninety', 100: 'hundred', 1000: 'onethousand'}

def expandByPlaceValue(num):
    count = len(str(num)) - 1
    thestr = str(num)
    otherstr = ""
    for char in thestr:
        for x in range(count):
            char += "0"
        if count == len(str(num)) - 1:
            otherstr += char
            count -= 1
            continue
        otherstr += "+" + char
        count -= 1
    return otherstr

def correct(num, strings):
    if int(str(num)[-2:]) in nums.keys():
        del strings[-2:]
        strings.append(nums[int(str(num)[-2:])])
    return strings


def convert(num):
    str = ""
    for x in expandByPlaceValue(num).split("+"):
        if x[0] != "1":
            str += nums[int(x[0])]
            l = list(x)
            l[0] = "1"
            x = ''.join(l)
        str += nums[int(x)] + " "
    str = correct(num, str.split(" "))
    return ','.join(str).replace(",", " ")



print(convert(978))
```

## EDITED AND DONE

Please fix your spellings of the numbers

Comment: It's damn well tested XD

Comment: This only converts a single number. You can iterate over the numbers, get the value, then append them to a string, then count while ignoring spaces and hyphens

Answer (score 0):

Use this code if you want `100` to be `one hundred`

```
nums = {0: '', 1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 5: 'five', 6: 'six', 7: 'seven', 8: 'eight', 9: 'nine',
              10: 'ten', 11: 'eleven', 12: 'twelve', 13: 'thirteen', 14: 'fourteen', 15: 'fifteen', 16: 'sixteen',
            17: 'seventeen', 18: 'eighteen', 19: 'nineteen', 20: 'twenty', 30: 'thirty', 40: 'forty', 50: 'fifty',
            60: 'sixty', 70: 'seventy', 80: 'eighty', 90: 'ninety', 100: 'hundred', 1000: 'onethousand'}

def expandByPlaceValue(num):
    count = len(str(num)) - 1
    thestr = str(num)
    otherstr = ""
    for char in thestr:
        for x in range(count):
            char += "0"
        if count == len(str(num)) - 1:
            otherstr += char
            count -= 1
            continue
        otherstr += "+" + char
        count -= 1
    return otherstr

def correct(num, strings):
    if int(str(num)[-2:]) in nums.keys():
        del strings[-2:]
        strings.append(nums[int(str(num)[-2:])])
    return strings


def convert(num):
    str1 = ""
    count = len(str(num)) - 1
    for x in expandByPlaceValue(num).split("+"):
        if x[0] and count > 1:
            str1 += nums[int(x[0])] + " "
            l = list(x)
            l[0] = "1"
            x = ''.join(l)
        str1 += nums[int(x)] + " "
        count -= 1
    str1 = correct(num, str1.split(" "))
    return ','.join(str1).replace(",", " ")



print(convert(int(input("Enter a number"))))
```